# Why command `ls -d` only print the `.` directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have tried `man ls`, and then I got

> ```
> -d, --directory
> ```
>
> list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

As the manual says, `-d` means listing all the directories, but when I type `ls -d`
I got

```
drwxr-xr-x 35 *user group* 4.0K *date* 00:16 .
```

Comment: Because, in absence of parameters, the only entry `.` is intended. Compare for example `ls -ld /bin` with `ls -l /bin`.

Comment: Read the manual again: `-d` does not mean “listing all the directories”.

Answer (score 14):

Because `ls` by default, references the current directory. That's the most common use case, after all: list the files in the current directory.

The "-d" flag just means "don't list files in the directory, just list the directory itself".

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstand the meaning of `-d` flag.

Comment: If you want to list just directories (in the present directory) use `ls -d */`, and if you want it to list hidden directories (those that start with `.`) in that output, use `shopt -s dotglob` before the ls.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list only the (not hidden) directories inside the current directory, try using `find` like this:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "\.*"`

Where:

- `-type d` focuses on directories only (which is what I assume you need)
- `-name "\.*"` searches for hidden files (`\` is to scape the `.` character)
- `-not` negates search for hidden files, so you are searching for not hidden files
- `-maxdepth 1` avoids to go inside further subdirectories

Comment: `-not` should be avoided in favour of `!`, the latter being POSIX. Moreover, the `\ ` in `\.*` can be left out